# am not able to get the value of label in table cell with index 0 in didselectrowwith indexpath method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, tags, tableview

i am setting a value of a label in the following delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I am able to see that value in table view too but wen i try to get the value in didselect method of table view i am getting null instead , that also only for 0th row.

Please help.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AMDEL_DCV.showmap=FALSE;
    AMDEL_DCV.indexno=indexPath.row;

    UITableViewCell *cell1=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lbltemp=(UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
        //AMDEL_DCV.distanceval is global in app delegate 
    AMDEL_DCV.distanceval=lbltemp.text; 
    NSLog(@"Label Text %@ and lbltemp teg%d",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lbltemp.text],lbltemp.tag);

    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];   
    LocationsMap *LM1catView=[[LocationsMap alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush]; 
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];  
    [[self.superview layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    [self.superview addSubview:LM1catView];
    [LM1catView release];
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're not actually getting a pointer to your UILabel, not that your UILabel's text is nil.  `-[UIView viewWithTag:]` will only return the sub view that has its `tag` property set to the value you're asking.  Because of the way UITableViewCells are reused, setting a different tag for the same label in each cell of at UITableView is probably a bad idea.  You may have better luck using `cell1.textLabel` instead.